# Windows python script remote execute Bash python script

Tags: python, linux, windows, bash

I have a python script which is being executed in windows. At a certain point in the script, I need to execute a separate python script which is sitting on a raspberry pi on the same network (which is running bash). I cannot use ssh to do this (due to a variety of reasons). Does anyone know another method by which I can do this?

Comment: Mount the Rpi containing the script directory locally on the window machine. Using SAMBA for example.